# What jmeter configuration I should use when running load test of 25 threads

Tags: jmeter, load

I need to run a load test of 25 threads, what will be the most efficient configuration to use? (ramp-up period....). I ran the load test with the below configuration and some of the threads failed but pass if I just ran the script individually.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration will mean that:

1. JMeter start with 1 thread and add another thread each 4 seconds
2. Once started each thread will begin to execute [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the logic controllers)
3. When the thread executes the last sampler it will be shut down
4. When the last thread executes the last sampler the test ends

Depending on the number of samplers and application response time you may or may not achieve 25 users concurrency, you might want to check the actual number of concurrent users using [Active Threads Over](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) Time listener

If you want to make sure to have 25 online users set "Loop Count" to `Infinite` and "Specify Thread Lifetime" duration to be more than your ramp-up period. See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article for more details.

With regards to the failures - we cannot state anything meaningful without seeing request and response details, make sure to save them using i.e. [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect response body for the failed requests

Comment: Dmitri, this is really good help! Thanks so much.